# How to count three columns by month mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, count, mysql-workbench

The table has 3 columns of filters(filter1, filter2, filter3) and a column with a date, you need to pull out each filter and calculate their number by month
There is a working request for one filter, but how to pull out 3 filters correctly with a monthly count?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT filter1, COUNT() AS 'Количество' 
       FROM   mosedo.doc_rows_og 
       WHERE  filter1 IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY filter1 
     ) AS a LEFT JOIN ( 
       SELECT filter1, COUNT() AS 'January ' 
       FROM   mosedo.doc_rows_og 
       WHERE  data_reg LIKE '%-01-%' 
       AND    filter1 IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY filter1
     ) as b USING(filter1) LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT filter1, COUNT(*) AS 'February ' 
       FROM   mosedo.doc_rows_og 
       WHERE  data_reg LIKE '%-02-%' 
       AND    filter1 IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY filter1
     ) as c using(filter1)
```

**Results:**

[image: Image of results]

**DDL & DML**

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e772ff3fd31899ddc8fcec646ffc437)*

```
CREATE TABLE `doc_rows_og` (
  `number_doc` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `data_reg` longtext,
  `komy` longtext,
  `ot_kogo` longtext,
  `soderjanie` longtext,
  `number_sogol` longtext,
  `number_otv` longtext,
  `srok_sam` longtext,
  `srok_isp` longtext,
  `fio_isp` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `status_` longtext,
  `porych` longtext,
  `vid` longtext,
  `istochink` longtext,
  `ot_kuda` longtext,
  `nomer` longtext,
  `status` longtext,
  `control` longtext,
  `name_object` longtext,
  `kto` longtext,
  `rezultat` longtext,
  `filter1` longtext,
  `filter2` longtext,
  `filter3` longtext,
  `dostovernost` longtext,
  `sujet` longtext,
  `opisanie` longtext,
  `prim` longtext,
  `type_object` longtext,
  `type` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number_doc`,`fio_isp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `mosedo`.`doc_rows_og` (`number_doc`, `data_reg`, `komy`, `ot_kogo`, `soderjanie`, `number_sogol`, `number_otv`, `srok_sam`, `srok_isp`, `fio_isp`, `status_`, `porych`, `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`) VALUES ('1', '2022-01-25', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'filterA', 'filterB', 'filterC');
INSERT INTO `mosedo`.`doc_rows_og` (`number_doc`, `data_reg`, `komy`, `ot_kogo`, `soderjanie`, `number_sogol`, `number_otv`, `srok_sam`, `srok_isp`, `fio_isp`, `status_`, `porych`, `filter2`, `filter3`) VALUES ('2', '2022-02-25', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'filterC', 'filterA');
INSERT INTO `mosedo`.`doc_rows_og` (`number_doc`, `data_reg`, `komy`, `ot_kogo`, `soderjanie`, `number_sogol`, `number_otv`, `srok_sam`, `srok_isp`, `fio_isp`, `status_`, `porych`, `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`) VALUES ('3', '2022-01-25', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'filterB', 'filterA', '');
INSERT INTO `mosedo`.`doc_rows_og` (`number_doc`, `data_reg`, `komy`, `ot_kogo`, `soderjanie`, `number_sogol`, `number_otv`, `srok_sam`, `srok_isp`, `fio_isp`, `status_`, `porych`, `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`) VALUES ('4', '2022-02-25', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'filterB', 'filterC', 'filterA');
```

- first column - filterA,filterB,filterC;
- second column - count where `data_reg like '%-01-%'` for each value from the first column;
- third column - count where `data_reg like '%-02-%'` for each value from the first column

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are aiming to get. The query is so messy.

Comment: It'd be easier for us to help if you included a small repro example. That means A) CREATE TABLE statement B) Some sample data as INSERT statements and C) Expected results as a table  - all in text form (*not* screen shots because we can't copy code from images).

Comment: @SOS I edit everything you asked

Comment: @lolqafoniya - Thank you. Using the sample data, could you show an example of the "expected" results? (Because I'm not quite sure, [something like this maybe...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=289fc0e824835cfc57a124313c173c8c)?  Also, is data_reg really type "longtext"? If so, it should be a DATE column, so you can use date functions.

Comment: @lolqafoniya - So are those the correct columns   (FilterValue, TotalRows, January, February) and results? If not, use the "Markdown" option to generate nicely formatted html. Modify the results to look the way you want, then paste it your question https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5906edf817aa964d425bdc960be620e5

Comment: @SOS - Yes, those are the correct columns and results. thanks again

Comment: @lolqafoniya - You're welcome. I'll write up an answer, in case it helps anyone else looking to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to merge all of the filter1,filter2 and filter3 values into a single column, you need a UNION ALL instead of a JOIN. Then use a conditional SUM() to count the number of rows by month.

*Note, the example uses [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) because the `data_reg` column stores dates as strings. Ideally you should change the data type of that column to DATE, so you can take better advantage of the available [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).*

```
SELECT FilterValue
      , COUNT(*) AS TotalRows
      , SUM(CASE WHEN month(str_to_date(data_reg, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS January
      , SUM(CASE WHEN month(str_to_date(data_reg, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS February
FROM (
         SELECT filter1 AS FilterValue, data_reg
         FROM   doc_rows_og
         WHERE  filter1 IS NOT NULL 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT filter2 AS FilterValue, data_reg
         FROM   doc_rows_og
         WHERE  filter2 IS NOT NULL 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT filter3 AS FilterValue, data_reg
         FROM   doc_rows_og
         WHERE  filter3 IS NOT NULL 
) t
WHERE FilterValue <> ''
GROUP BY FilterValue
;
```

**Results:**

> ```
> FilterValue | TotalRows | January | February
> :---------- | --------: | ------: | -------:
> filterA     |         4 |       2 |        2
> filterB     |         3 |       2 |        1
> filterC     |         3 |       1 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4f0745d2b56afabe52b2e017605c6e3)*

Comment: Fixed a typo in the "February" column. It should obviously be `month(....) = 2` instead of  `month(....) = 1`.  See updated fiddle.